# How to add multiple rows and how to replace value in spire Doc using c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I have doc file and i want replace string values in table and also add row in doc file and convert it into PDF. 
Example. I have 5 records in data table then add 5 rows with records in existing spire doc and replace values.
 Please check attached photo of doc file.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you use mail merge which would be much easier.

First, modify your template word document by inserting merge fields like below:

[image]

Second, refer to below example code to merge data in a datatable to the word table:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using Spire.Doc;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            //load word document
            document.LoadFromFile("template.docx");

            //convert datatable to list
            DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
            DataSet dsTmp = new DataSet();
            dsTmp.Tables.Add(dt);
            List<DictionaryEntry> list = new List<DictionaryEntry>();
            DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry = new DictionaryEntry("Table", string.Empty);
            list.Add(dictionaryEntry);

            //merge data in list to word table
            document.MailMerge.ExecuteWidthNestedRegion(dsTmp, list);

            //save the result document to pdf
            //document.SaveToFile("Result.docx", FileFormat.Docx2013);
            document.SaveToFile("Result.pdf", FileFormat.PDF);
        }

        public static DataTable GetDataTable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.TableName = "Table";

            dt.Columns.Add("srno", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("particulars", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("finish", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("thickness", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("size", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("chargeable", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("unit", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("rateUnit", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("total", typeof(string));

            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1["srno"] = "A";
            dr1["particulars"] = "20";
            dr1["finish"] = "1";
            dr1["thickness"] = "$1000";
            dr1["size"] = "A";
            dr1["chargeable"] = "20";
            dr1["unit"] = "1";
            dr1["rateUnit"] = "$1000";
            dr1["total"] = "A";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

            DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
            dr2["srno"] = "B";
            dr2["particulars"] = "20";
            dr2["finish"] = "1";
            dr2["thickness"] = "$1500";
            dr2["size"] = "B";
            dr2["chargeable"] = "20";
            dr2["unit"] = "1";
            dr2["rateUnit"] = "$1500";
            dr2["total"] = "B";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

            DataRow dr3 = dt.NewRow();
            dr3["srno"] = "C";
            dr3["particulars"] = "20";
            dr3["finish"] = "1";
            dr3["thickness"] = "$1500";
            dr3["size"] = "C";
            dr3["chargeable"] = "20";
            dr3["unit"] = "1";
            dr3["rateUnit"] = "$1500";
            dr3["total"] = "C";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr3);

            return dt;
        }        
    }
}
```

[image]

If you don't want to use mail merge, you need to add rows to the word table using `table.AddRow();`, then assign the datatable value to word table by loop(`table.Rows[i].Cells[j].AddParagraph().AppendText(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But i tried it in different ways.

Comment: what do you mean the "Table" in:
DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry = new DictionaryEntry("Table", string.Empty);

Answer (score 0):

After some efforts i get solution. You can check it below code.

```
        Table table = doc.Sections[0].Tables[0] as Table;

        foreach (var item in Qu.Product)
        {
            ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
            arrList.Add(a);
            arrList.Add(item.Parti);
            arrList.Add(item.Fin);
            arrList.Add(item.Thick);
            arrList.Add(item.Size);
            arrList.Add(item.Charge);
            arrList.Add(item.Unit);
            arrList.Add(item.RateUnit);
            arrList.Add(item.Total);

            TableRow Trow = table.AddRow();

            for (int row = 1; row <= 1; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
                {
                    Trow.Cells[col].AddParagraph().AppendText(arrList[col].ToString());
                }
            }
            a++;
        }
```